# async.mapSeries with a nested callback function and variable scope

Tags: node.js, node-async

My problem is with variable scope, async.mapSeries and nested call back functions. I need to iterate a collection and call a stored procedure based on a values in the collection.

So far my code is as follows

```
var _var1 = "";

LoadData(sp, callback)
{
    //mysql stuff
    connection.connect();

    var query = connection.query(sp, function(err, rows, fields){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        connection.end();
        callback(rows[0]);
    });
}

otherfunction() {

    //retdata returned from another function 

    async.mapSeries(retdata,function(rd, rdCb){

        LoadData(options, function (row) {
            var _content = new Buffer(row[0].content, 'base64').toString('ascii');
            //can't get _content to the callback, and _var1 isn't in scope here       
        });
        //next     
        rdCb();
    },function(err,results){
        //need _content accessible here to iterate through data 
    });
```

any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the callback synchronously, which defeats the point of using the `async` module.  You should pass the data to the callback:

```
async.mapSeries(retdata,function(rd, rdCb){
    LoadData(options, function (row) {
        var _content = new Buffer(row[0].content, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        rdCb(null, _content);
    });
},function(err,results){
    //_results is now what you expect
});
```

Comment: when I tried it that way, it never advanced to the next item in the collection. Thanks I'll give it another crack. *LoadData is a callback function in itself

Comment: @BadWolf If it never advances to the next item, that means `LoadData` is failing to call its callback.

Comment: spot on, one of my functions wasn't calling the callback assigned to it. Finally got this async down now!